# How to use a private python github package in an Azure function app?

Tags: azure, github, pip, azure-functions

I have a private github package that I can install in my azure function app locally with:

```
pip install git+https://git@github.com/org-name/package-name.git
```

When I run the function locally (`func start`) everything works as expected. But when I publish it:

```
func azure functionapp publish "app" --python
```

It fails during the pip install step:

```
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/org-name/package-name' /tmp/pip-req-build-7f2uwfvf
  Host key verification failed.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This is expected since it is a remote build and I have specified no credentials but my question is HOW to make it work. A possible solution is using a personal access token in my requirements.txt (in the link to the package) but I do not want to hardcode it there. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You need **to add PAT token** in order ***to install a private package from your github repository***, But instead of hardcoding the PAT token just add it as an environment variable in your VS Code Terminal or the Terminal in which you are running you Function and then Run your function with **`fn + f5`** or just by **`f5`**.

***Set the PAT token as environment variable like below:-***

```
setx export GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_hUkGEHxxxxxxxxxhVKc
```

[image]

**My requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
git+https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/sid24desai/pycode.git@main
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

*You can also set this as a secret in your Github Repository and then use it as a environment variable in the build step while building and deploying your Function in Azure Function App.*

I have added the PAT Token as a Variable in my Github Repository secrets like below:-

[image]

**My requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
git+https://$env.PAT_TOKEN@github.com/sid24desai/pycode.git@main
```

[image]

***Now In your Azure Function App > Deployment  Center > Select the Repository above and click on save to enable Azure Function deployment:-***

[image]

***My Github Action YAML script:-***

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - funcapp9sil

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' 
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'funcapp9sil'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_65FCDE1DD41942BB986ADB4791139047 }}
```

My Github Action Pipeline with Build and Deploy step to Deploy the Function in the Function App:-

[image]

[image]

[image]